# Plotting a Transcendental Function

Tags: graphing-functions, transcendental-equations

How would I plot $m_{2}$ as a function of $m_{1}$ for $0.5< m_{1} < 10$, for the following equation:

$$\frac{\sin(m_{2})}{(m_{1}+m_{2})^{2}} = \alpha,$$

where $\alpha$ is a non-zero constant? I cannot solve for $m_{2}$ in terms of $m_{1}$.

Any suggestion would be appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: If you have plotting software, substitute x and y variables for the m_1 and m_2 , the result is something of a surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica, follwing @Alan's advice. ($x$ is going left to right, $y$ is going bottom to top, like usual).

[image]

Comment: To clarify, I picked $\alpha = .55$ and the boundry of the grey region is the graph of the function.